# max-width: 100% + max-height: 100% doesn't work on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari, safari

Have a look a this url:
http://www.preen.me/product/1113142/

The product box on the left has the class `product_pic`, and contains an `img` tag with these CSS attributes:

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%
```

This is to ensure that the image fits proportionally in the box.

It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and all other proper modern browsers on PC:

[image]

It does not work in mobile Safari. Specifically, if you try to look at this page on an **iPad in landscape mode** the image simply disappears:

[image]

I think this is a rendering issue in mobile Safari but I'm at a loss as to how to solve it. Removing either one of the max-width\max-life properties brings back the image, but obviously without the required functionality. How can I go around this?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember it, this is fixed by setting html/body tag to width/height 100%.

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And don't forget to set all divs up to the div where it should have effecto to width/height 100%.

Also you can **try** to set the html,body to position: relative. I'm no longer sure about this one.

Comment: ow yeah, and don't forget about the overflow hidden ... But I was assuming you already did that.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions. Other than playing with `"overflow:hidden"`, you can try adding default values for width and height or simply play around by using `"width:auto"` or `"height:auto"` or both. You may also want to set `"float:left"`.

Hope this solves your problem (at least partially).

happy coding :)

Comment: I can't add default values for width and height because this is a grid-based responsive design. `width:auto` and  `height:auto` will not stretch an image to a container. Set `float:left` on what? And what for?

Comment: I am not really clear as to why you can't set default values for product_pic (grid-based responsive design in no way interferes with this). Anyways, have you tried playing with the orientation media queries to set more specific values in the landscape mode? i.e, (@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .product_pic { width: 22%; }
}

Comment: It has everything to do with the responsive grid. `product_pic` gets its size from `container_product_pic` which is defined by the grid to be the size of 3 columns out of the available 12, 2 out of 8 or 4 out of 4 depending on the viewport size. Change the browser width and you'll see the image dimensions changing as the columns change. That's why I can't put default values - there is no set size for the product image.

Comment: even as % ? like width:100% ?

Comment: `product_pic` already has default values of `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. If you're referring to setting default values for the actual `IMG` inside  it - `width: 100%` will not allow the image to fit proportionally into the box. If the image has a portrait ratio, and its width is set to 100%, then its height will be larger than its width thus not fitting into the square box.